# How to fetch the conversation id from a .msg file using MAPIMessage

Tags: java, outlook, apache-poi

I'm trying to parse a .msg file. How do I get the **conversation id**? 
I'm using org.apache.poi.hsmf.MAPIMessage

Answer (score 1):

The structure of the MSG file format is described in the MSDN library, see [[MS-OXMSG]: Outlook Item (.msg) File Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxmsg/b046868c-9fbf-41ae-9ffb-8de2bd4eec82).

Answer (score 1):

It is stored in the `0x0F030102` property - you can see if it is set in a particular MSG file in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author - click OpenIMsgOnIStg button).